# How to use loc in pandas dataframe slicing?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
ce["Buy_Price"] = ce["Trade_price"][ce["Trade_type"] == "CE Buy"]
```

How to use loc in this line to avoid warning........."A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: Pls explain what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give "Buy_Price" the value of "Trade_price" when [ce["Trade_type"] == "CE Buy"] you can use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
ce["Buy_Price"] = np.where(ce["Trade_type"] == "CE Buy", ce["Trade_price"], ce["Buy_Price"])
```

If you still want to use `.loc`:

```
ce.loc[ce['Trade_type']=='CE Buy','Buy_Price'] = ce['Trade_price']
```

Regarding your followup question about: `ce = df[(df["Trade_type"] == "CE Buy") | (df["Trade_type"] == "CE Sell")]`:
This code should work ok.
However, you can make it better like:

```
types = ['CE Sell', 'CE Buy']
ce = df[df['Trade_type'].isin(types)]
```

Comment: all are giving correct answers but as well as all are throwing same

Comment: The first one - using 'where' cannot give the same. The second one - on my dataframe does not.

Comment: Please post the result of 'ce.dtypes'

Comment: Datetime        object
Symbol          object
Trade_price    float64
Trade_type      object
Buy_Price      float64
Sell_Price     float64
P/L            float64
dtype: object

Comment: This is all fine. Wou should not have any problem with my answer above

Comment: @gtomer..i located the error..it was showing for........ ce = df[(df["Trade_type"] == "CE Buy") | (df["Trade_type"] == "CE Sell")] ..how can i solve this also??

Comment: See above updated answer. However, the new line that you posted should not give you an error either

Comment: @gtomer it would give the error as ce is a slice of df, the error is saying that you're trying to make changes to slice of the original database, rather than a copy of it which can cause unwanted results. If you add `.copy()` on to the end of the df filter, the errors should go :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use .loc in this way to correct the warning.

`ce["Buy_Price"] = ce.loc[:]["Trade_price"][ce["Trade_type"] == "CE Buy"]`

in general:

`df['new_column_name'] = df.loc[:][old_column_name][boolean condition]`